# POST route not working with laravel

Tags: laravel, post, http-post

Here is test chunk of code from routes.php

```
Route::post('testPost', function(){
    echo "Post received";
});
```

When I hit it with POST request I get 500 Internal server error, but if I change first line so it handles get requests like:

```
Route::get('testPost', function(){
...
```

everything works fine.

Here is my .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options +FollowSymLinks
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Does anyone have an idea what can be the solution?

Comment: What do your server logs say is throwing the error?

Answer (score 0):

May be you are not accessing the url properly. I mean the /testPost path receive only post request. You told that you hit it with POST request, but how have you done it? Have you done it properly? Have you done it using form submission using post method or you are using any REST client(e.g. Postman) to do post request?

Summery is, you code is absolute fine and it should work perfectly for post request. There may have some mistake with accessing the url.

Comment: I've done it using hurl.it. POST request is sent on address http://ip_address/API-test/public/testPost

Comment: And if I change request type to GET and alter first line in routes.php, it works fine

Comment: As I said there is no noting wrong with the code here, there might be something wrong in way you are accessing. By the way you can see the registered routes using artisan command. The command is: php artisan routes

Comment: I've checked that and the route is registered.

Comment: Then you should check the url by any other REST client(e.g. Postman).